# Is there a function in numbers that allows to select elements that have an index congruent to 2 modulo 3 for its row, from a given column?

Tags: numbers, software

I want to select and do the average of one every 3 numbers and the row index of the first is 5. So I want to select 5,8,11 etc

Is there a way to do it in Numbers?